# Stopping a PHP loop when updating MySQL database

Tags: php

I'm creating a basic main menu for a stock market simulator where the price of a company will be updated periodically. For testing purposes, I need to make a loop to display the price of a share on the website five times (with the website automatically updating without refreshing) and to update the database at the same time.

I have successfully wrote some code which will both update the database with the current share price and will also update the website as well. However, when I have tried to include a loop I have come to a problem. I have included a loop to iterate five times but the problem that I am having is that the code continues to iterate even after five tries.

PHP:

```
<?php
  $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "prices");
  if ($conn->connect_error)
  {
    die("Connection error: ". $conn->connect_error);
  }
  $result = $conn->query("SELECT `price` FROM `priceTable` WHERE `company` = 'Bawden'");
  $x = 0;
    if ($result->num_rows > 0)
    {
      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
      {
        echo $row['price'];
        echo '<br><br>';
        echo $x;
        if ($x < 5)
        {
          $random = (rand(3300, 3700) / 100);
          $sql = $conn->query("UPDATE `priceTABLE` SET `price` = '$random' WHERE `company` = 'Bawden'");
          $x++;
        }
      }
    }
?>
```

The above code will be displayed in a separate document with Javascript code and I can post this if required in the original post however I originally chose not to as I believe this is a PHP only problem. I have chosen to display $x to see if the value will increment. However, when running, the value of $x will stay at 0.

My expected result is that, on the website, there will only be five different updates and in the database, the database will only be updated five times.

However, my actual result is that the website and database are both continuously being updated, not stopping after five times.

Comment: Use `break;` to break out of the loop. Currently, your code will keep iterating through all the result set, but it will only run the update-code 5 times.

Comment: Hi @Shadow, move  the  $x = 0;  declaration to inside your while loop so that it resets for each row you read from $result.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to mix all that stuff together? This will get pretty messy once your application grows

Comment: @Dugggie - How would that stop the loop after 5 times? That would reset the counter on each iteration.

Comment: @ Magnus Eriksson Yes I just realised that myself. @Leo Chashchin, are you trying to only process 5 rows from your database regardless of how many rows are returned ? Or are you trying to limit the UPDATE commands to only 5 updates ?

Comment: @Dugggie I'm trying to limit the update command to only 5 updates yes. At the moment, for testing purposes, there is only one company in my database with one price only. So I'm updating this one company's price five times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to limit the update command to only 5 updates yes. At the
>   moment, for testing purposes, there is only one company in my database
>   with one price only. So I'm updating this one company's price five
>   times

If you need to do the update 5 times for each row returned from the database, change your `if` statement to a `for` loop. Change this :-

```
 if ($x < 5)
    {
      $random = (rand(3300, 3700) / 100);
      $sql = $conn->query("UPDATE `priceTABLE` SET `price` = '$random' WHERE `company` = 'Bawden'");
      $x++;
    }
```

to this

```
for ($x = 0, $x < 5, $x++)
{
      $random = (rand(3300, 3700) / 100);
      $sql = $conn->query("UPDATE `priceTABLE` SET `price` = '$random' WHERE `company` = 'Bawden'");
}
```

This will repeat the process exactly 5 times and not rely on a separate counter (remove the other references to $x). Not sure why you would want to update the same record 5 times with different random values though.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I ended up figuring it out in the end (but was unsure as to whether or not to leave my question up or to take it down) but I used the method that you posted above by changing my 'if' to a 'for' loop.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think the loop should stop after 5 iterations?

You need to add the condition `$x<5` in the `while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())`

**Edit following your comment**

What you initially wrote is something like `loop hundreds of times if need be and do something in the first 5 occurrences (starting loop 6, keep looping but do nothing)`.

Now for the 2nd half of your comment, I'm not sure what you mean.
What I see in your code is:

1. Select all prices for `company = 'Bawden'`
2. Update **all** the prices for `company = 'Bawden'` 5 times (loop) with a random value, the same one, on all the records.

Not enough information to tell for sure but I don't think it makes sense: on one hand, you except to have several records under `company = 'Bawden` (= reason why you created a loop), on the other hand, your update feels like it is written under the assumption there would be 1 record only...
Are you missing something like a price date from your table? What is the primary key of `priceTable`?

Try to post more technical details about your table (definition, sample of data) or it will be complicated to help further.

Comment: I thought it should stop if the value of $x will reach 5. I have included the $x < 5 within my while loop and as a result the value of x incremented, however the price did not display and looking inside my database, the price table continued to update itself in the background.

Comment: Apologies if this did seem ambiguous. I'll try to simplify the problem that I am having, if possible.

Within my database, I have a table called priceTable with three columns: companyID, company and price. In the future, I will have ten companies each with their own respective companyID and current price. The random number generated is only a test to see if what I am aiming for will happen. At the moment, I am currently working with one company and whenever a new price for that company is generated, the database should replace the old one with the new price.

Comment: What I need to do is for the value of the price for this company to be displayed when the user will visit the main page, then for the PHP code to generate a new price, to update this new price in the database and to update it on the website. I would like this to happen five times. After five times, I would like the script to stop running and generating new numbers / updating the database.

Comment: Let's say you update it 5 times (= put `x < 5` in the `while`), then won't that simply make the first 4 values discarded?

Comment: It would however when I have tried this, the program continues, even after 5 times, to keep generating numbers and updating the database and website.

Answer (score 0):

```
  The else will break the first loop, the second one will stop on the first while loop.



while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
              {
                echo $row['price'];
                echo '<br><br>';
                echo $x;
                if ($x < 5)
                {
                  $random = (rand(3300, 3700) / 100);
                  $sql = $conn->query("UPDATE `priceTABLE` SET `price` = '$random' WHERE `company` = 'Bawden'");
                  $x++;
                }else{
    break;
    }
    break;
              }
```

Comment: I have tried adding both break's to the end of my statements but still no success. I am still encountering the same problem: an endless repetition of generated prices and no incremented value of $x.

Comment: Change the last break for exit(), the aplication will stop.

Comment: Still have the same error. I have my code exactly how you have displayed it above and, apart from a separate file which just displays the code above, there is nothing else to it.